# Is there any surveillance camera that supports UDP broadcast upon motion detection?

Tags: protocols, wireless, ethernet

I use EventGhost as my IoT hub. The easiest way for me to hook it up with a surveillance cam is UDP broadcast.

So my question:
Is there any surveillance camera that supports UDP broadcast upon motion detection?

Comment: Considering you tagged this wireless & ethernet I assume you don't care which it is? Do you want to buy a camera or build one?

Comment: 1. A lot of cams seem to lack ethernet = beggars can't be choosers
2. I want to buy

Comment: Welcome aboard. While this is a good question for this site, you should also be aware of https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Quite a few questions could be asked on either site. No problem with asking here, I just wanted to make you aware of the other :-)

Answer (score 5):

The program MJPG_streamer has an UDP option. This program is commonly used with DIY security cameras running embedded Linux. This program does not allow motion detection however. You must sync the stream to a monitoring program such as Zoneminder. The motion detection program Motion also allows UDP, but mentions this: The TCP transport is highly preferred because without this option the rtsp/rtmp images are frequently corrupted and result in many false positive values and images that appear to be smeared.

If you are looking for a hardware camera that, by default, uses UDP, I don't know of any off-hand. I use a D-Link DCS932 camera, but it allows third party firmware, so I flash with OpenWrt and install mjpg_streamer & motion.

Comment: I saw that D-Links cams have UDP but they don't mention to what extent they support it. I don't really need the images to be transferred via UDP just the actual "hey, something's happening" msg :)

Comment: Dud you contact them to ask?